# Can I use the median of a Percent to show growth?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm not that great at math since I have not really had to do any since High School. I want to make sure what I am doing is correct. If I have percent increases that represent our growth each month for a blog, can I use the median of that number as a fair representation?

Growth:
M1 2,238%
M2 54%
M3 1.9%
M4 28%
M5 15%
M6 29%
M7 204%

Median I got was 29

Also, does this mean I say I have 129% growth median or I have 29% growth median because some people get confused and if I say we have 29% growth they actually ask if my numbers went down (even though I said growth)? So this makes me think I am doing this wrong.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably a geometric mean. If over $n$ periods, we had an $r_j$ percent growth in each period, the preferred representation of the "average growth" is the growth rate $\hat{r}$ such that $(1 + r)^n = (1+r_1)(1+r_2) \cdots (1 + r_n)$. That is, we want the growth rate $\hat{r}$ such that if that growth rate had been constant over all $n$ periods, we would end with the same value. That value is given by $\hat{r} = [(1+r_1)(1+r_2) \cdots (1 + r_n)]^{1/n} - 1$

Comment: Joe's answer is spot on. Now mrhobbeys might want more details: he has $n=7$, $r_1 = 22.38$, $r_2 = 0.54$ etc. Use a good calculator to get your answer, or do it with WolframAlpha.

Comment: Thank you. I do have Wolfram on my Raspberry Pi so I will dig it out and give it a shot :)